# Saving a value and using it later in the command chain

Tags: cypress, drag

I'm testing a drag scenario, want to get an elements position and use the value in a mousemove. I though that Cypress.env() was a way to save values, but it appears empty in the mousemove parameters. How do I save the initial data?

```js
cy.get('.draggable')
  .then($el => { Cypress.env('start', $el[0].getBoundingClientRect()) })
  .trigger('mousemove', , { pageX: Cypress.env('start').x +20 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test commands take their values as the test is run, but the commands run later (asynchronously), so `Cypress.env('start')` is not yet defined when the mousemove command is queued.

You can add a `.then()` to delay queueing that command, and it will read the latest value.

```js
cy.get('.draggable')
  .then($el => { Cypress.env('start', $el[0].getBoundingClientRect()) })
  .then($el => {
    cy.wrap($el).trigger('mousemove', { pageX: Cypress.env('start').x +20 })
  })
```